# Soliton solution of the NLS equation

Tags: optics, waves, solitons, non-linear-schroedinger

My understanding of soliton - it is a moving pulse in a medium which does not change its structure with time. It has other properties like no interaction with other solitons (this could certainly be wrong. Please let me know if I am getting this wrong)

When reading a book on the topic, the author mentions that the NLS (Non-linear Schrödinger) equation has a special solution of the form-

$u(z,t) = sech(t)exp(iz/2)$
which is claimed to be a *fundamental soliton*.

Taking the modulus of the equation yields a function independent of $z$. Now I get terribly confused. Why is the modulus of $u(z,t)$ independent of $z$? Shouldn't a soliton pulse's form change with $z$ for a fixed $t$?

Edit: Earlier in the book, it is mentioned that $t$ "represents retarded time, i.e., ordinary
time, but with the transit time delay of a pulse at the central frequency subtracted
off". So is the author saying that $u(z,t)$ is the equation of the profile of a soliton and not the soliton itself?

Comment: I think you should provide a bit more information : NLS -denotes non-linear Schroedinger equation, as far as I understand, it would be more convenient for the audience to see it written explicitly, or reference(extract from the aforementioned book).

Comment: Good idea @spiridon_the_sun_rotator. I have edited the question to reflect that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The usual soliton for the NLS is
$$
\psi(x,t)=e^{ikx-i\omega t}\sqrt{\frac{\alpha}{m\lambda}}{\rm sech}(\sqrt{\alpha}(x-Ut)
$$
where $m$ is the mass and $\lambda$ is the coeficient of the $|\psi|^2\psi$ term. The parameters  $\alpha$ and $U$ are arbitrary. Your book has  interchanged the role of $x$ and $t$.
I suspect that it deals with  optical fibres in which one has electic field modes
$$
E(x,t)= A(x,t)e^{ikx-\omega t}
$$ where
$
A
$ obeys a NLS with the role of $x$ and $t$ reversed.  For details see [here](https://goldbart.gatech.edu/PostScript/MS_PG_book/bookmaster.pdf) page 287.